# Handling Ajax request feedback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After I've done a MySQL operation I have the following lines of code (I've tried each one of them):

```
if($done){
  echo json_encode("done");
  flush();
}

if($done){
  echo "done";
}
```

and in the Javascript side I have:

```
done(function(data) {
    if(data){
        alert(data);
        console.log(data=="done");
```

Although the data appears correctly in the alert, the "console.log" always displays false. I've tried without the *" "* and with *' " " '* and what else but it just won't work. Any idea on why?

Comment: Try simple `console.log(data);` what do you get?

Comment: @kingkero an odd " done ", with strange spaces. The thing is I also tried to match it with " done " but yet, nothing, and " done", "done ", etc...

Comment: What happens if you replace that last line with `console.log(data.trim()=="done");`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what was said in the comments, you have whitespace surrounding the `data` value. Trim off that whitespace with the `trim()` function (available on up-to-date browsers):

```
console.log(data.trim()=="data");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of you're PHP code you've used json encode to put the php output into a javascript object but you haven't parsed this using JSON.parse() in your js.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Perhaps just use the PHP code that just echos the text:

```
if($done){
  echo "done";
}
```

Also you can output a JS object to the console as follows:

```
console.log("%O", data);
```